# python write to same file using multiple subprocess in a for loop

Tags: python, file, file-io, fwrite

I am trying to write the output of several subprocess python program to a same file. The main python program looks like this:

```
forums = ["f20","e70","x3","e89","series7","m5","f10","series6","z4e85","i3i8","f22","f80","f15","f48","f87"]

for f in forums:
        command = "python 01-measurevariation.py "+ f+"-commoncrawl-timestamp.csv-excludeunif"
        print command
        exit_status = subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

And the subprocess python program 01-measurevariation.py is here(showing only related codes):

```
    input_file= str(sys.argv[1])
    output_file = "tsvariations.csv"
    ...
    with open(input_file) as to_read:
        with open(output_file, "wb") as tmp_file:
            reader = csv.reader(to_read, delimiter = ",")
            writer = csv.writer(tmp_file)
            ....
            writer.writerow (["variance of "+sys.argv[1]+" is "+"%.2f" % numpy.var(difflist)+ " hours"])
            writer.writerow (["std of "+sys.argv[1]+" is "+ "%.2f" % numpy.std(difflist) +" hours"])
```

However, the output file "tsvariations.csv" only contains 2 lines, which is the output of the last subprocess in the for loop in the main python program.

I want the tsvariations.csv to contain all subprocess output, which should have a total of 30 lines. (2 lines for each of the 15 entries in "forums" list). How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Open the file in append mode.

Comment: that works perfect for me! Thank you spectras!

Answer (score 0):

> **Resolved in comments:**
>    Open the file in append mode. – spectras yesterday